# Windows randomly request Smartcard/Token PIN when multiple processes of my application are running at same time

Tags: c#, authentication, cryptography, smartcard, x509certificate2

In my application, I use the System.Net.WebClient to communicate with a website server that requires an user Certificate for SSL Authentication, which can be stored in an external smart card/token device. I use the Windows CSP to gain access to a validated X509Certificate2 instance.

I can access the Certificate stored in a Smartcard/Reader or Token with no problem when it's just a single Windows Process of the application running. The Process can run for more than one hour, sending many Http request thru the System.Net.WebClient (with the Certificate attached to it)

The problem is that, when more than one Windows Process (of the same application/solution) run at the same time, using the same Certificate from the Smartcard/Token, after some elapsed time (few minutes) the Applications starts to request the User PIN in the Windows Default PIN UI (that NEVER happen when is just a single process running).

Even if I manually inform the correctly PIN in the UI, the System.Net.WebClient FAILS to perform its operation and a new Process needs to be booted in order for the Smartcard/Token Certificate to work again.

Below I explain and provide the sample codes that I use in my solution:

First I retrieve an System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 from the Windows Keystore, which is related/attached to the Smartcard/Token:

```
private X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate()
    {
        X509Store KeyStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        KeyStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        var clientCert = GetClientCertFromCollection(KeyStore.Certificates);
    }
```

From the clientCert instance above, it's just the public key because of I still can't access the private key from it.
In order to gain access to the private key in the Smartcard/Token, I perform a "handshake" with the device/hardware
attached using the Microsoft/Windows Cryptography Service Provider (CSP). Below the code:

```
private void WithHardwareDeviceHandshake(X509Certificate2 certificate, SecureString securePassword)
    {
        if (certificate.HasPrivateKey == false)
            throw new CertificateException("The private key  Não foi encontrada a chave privada associada ao Certificado Digital");

        var cspAsymmetricAlgorithm = certificate.PrivateKey as ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm;
        if (cspAsymmetricAlgorithm == null)
            throw new CertificateException($"Not an instance of {nameof(ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm)}");

        var keyContainer = cspAsymmetricAlgorithm.CspKeyContainerInfo;
        if (keyContainer == null)
            throw new CertificateException($"The {nameof(CspKeyContainerInfo)} is null. Its not possible to access the private key.");

        if (keyContainer.HardwareDevice == false || keyContainer.Removable == false)
            throw new CertificateException($"The Certificate Serial Number {certificate.SerialNumber} is not associated with an Smartcard/Token device.");

        CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters(
            keyContainer.ProviderType,
            keyContainer.ProviderName,
            keyContainer.KeyContainerName,
            new System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeySecurity(),
            securePassword);

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters);

        if (certificate.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(false) != rsaProvider.ToXmlString(false))
            throw new CertificateException($"The Certificate with the Serial Number {certificate.SerialNumber} accessed in the Windows Keystore was not found on the Smartcard/Token.");
    }
```

After the above handshake if performed I can freely access the private key from the smartcard/token device because I provided the PIN to it.
Following it I build a CertificateCollection with all the Certification Authority tree/chain:

```
public X509Certificate2Collection BuildX509CertificateChainCollection(X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        if (cert == null)
            return null;

        X509Certificate2Collection certificationChainCollec = new X509Certificate2Collection();


        X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
        chain.Build(cert);
        foreach (X509ChainElement chainElementItem in chain.ChainElements)
            certificationChainCollec.Add(chainElementItem.Certificate);

        return certificationChainCollec;
    }
```

The certificationChainCollec above is provided to the System.Net.WebClient every time it needs to perform a Web Request.
In order to do that, I specialize the class:

```
public class HttpWebClientEngine : System.Net.WebClient
{           
    public HttpWebClientEngine(X509CertificateCollection collection) : base()
    {
        this.CertCollection = collection;
    }
    
    private X509CertificateCollection CertCollection { get; set; }
    
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        DecorateRequestWithCertificate(request);
        return request;
    }
    
    private void DecorateRequestWithCertificate(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        if (CertCollection?.Count > 0)
            request.ClientCertificates.AddRange(CertCollection);
    }
    
}
```

Then I simply use it to perform HTTP GET/POST Requests:

```
public class HttpWebClient : IDisposable
{
    public X509CertificateCollection CertCollection { get; set; }
    
    private WebClient CreateWebClient()
    {
        this.ValidateKeepAliveHeader();
        var webClient = new HttpWebClientEngine(this.CertCollection);
        return webClient;
    }
    
    public string PostMethod(Uri uri, Payload contentData)
    {
        using (var client = this.CreateWebClient())
        {
            var webResponse = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                var data = contentData.Data;
                webResponse = client.UploadString(uri, data ?? String.Empty);
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
            {
                webResponse = new StreamReader(((WebException)ex).Response?.GetResponseStream())?.ReadToEnd() ?? string.Empty;
            }

            return webResponse;
        }                           
    }
    
    public string GetMethod(Uri uri)
    {
        using (var client = this.CreateWebClient())
        {
            var webResponse = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                webResponse = client.DownloadString(uri);
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
            {
                webResponse = new StreamReader(((WebException)ex).Response?.GetResponseStream())?.ReadToEnd() ?? string.Empty;
            }
            return webResponse;
        }
    }
    
}
```